# DataContext.Submit and TransactionScope

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, transactionscope, submitchanges

Please explain me pseudocode below.

My idea is: 3-nd SubmitChanges will commit o.Status and will not commit o.TransactionId, and my object will get corrupted in database (I mean it will not be consistent anymore).

```
XDataContext DB = .....; 
XOrder o = DB.XOrders.Single(.......);

try
{
    using (var t = new TransactionScope())
    {
        o.Status = XOrderStatus.Completed;
        DB.SubmitChanges(); // 1
        string s = null;
        s.Trim(); // crash here;
        o.TransactionId = ......; // some calculations here
        DB.SubmitChanges(); // 2
        t.Complete();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    XEvent e = new XEvent();
    e.Type = XEventType.Exception;
    e.Data = .........; // some calculations here
    DB.XEvents.InsertOnSubmit(e);
    DB.SubmitChanges(); // 3
}
```

Is it any 'best practices' for my case?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it any 'best practices' for my case?

Yes.  Use one DataContext instance per unit of work.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    XEvent e = new XEvent();
    e.Type = XEventType.Exception;
    e.Data = .........; // some calculations here
   using (XDataContext dc2 = new XDataContext())
   {
    dc2.XEvents.InsertOnSubmit(e);
    dc2.SubmitChanges(); // 3
   }
}
```